# With the actual Android Wear SDK I can only develop notification related Apps? Or there is more?

Tags: android, wear-os

I just wanted to know if right now Android Wear is only limited to notifications from apps from other device...There is very poor info on the Google Developer portal for Android Wear and can't get any straight answer from any other question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, there is more. :)

You can still use customized notifications (now via the `NotificationCompat.WearableExtender` class) so that they are more useful on drawables.

But in addition, API level 20 is Android 4.4W, and it allows [developing Wear applications](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html) with very much the same stack as standard Android apps (i.e. Activities, Services, Layouts, Views, &c) although the Design and UI are logically very different. An unofficial library provides custom views (such as `CardFragment`, `WearableListView`, &c) that help in this regard.

When developing applications, you can install them directly into the Android Wear device, but for final users the Wearable app must be *embedded* into the standard application, and it will be automatically pushed to the wearable after the app is installed. Android Studio helps with these parts.

There is also an API to facilitate communication between an app installed on the Wearable and its corresponding app on the handheld device. See [Sending and Syncing Data](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html) in the documentation.

In short, you should start by checking the documentation on [Building Apps for Wearables](http://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html), and then creating a New Project in Android Studio and marking the "Wear" checkbox.

---

**OLD ANSWER (pre I/O, now deprecated)**

That is correct. As of today (June 13) the Developer Preview only supports notifications (plus some Wear-specific add-ons such as pages and voice replies).

From http://developer.android.com/wear/preview/start.html

> With the Android Wear Developer Preview, you can:
>
> - Run the Android Wear platform in the Android emulator.
> - Connect your Android device to the emulator and view notifications from the device as cards on Android Wear.
> - Try new APIs in the preview support library that enhance your app's notifications with features such as voice replies and notification
>     pages.

Installing apps directly on the Wear emulator is not supported. It's very likely that Google I/O will bring news on this front, but just speculation at this point.

The situation is more or less similar to what happened with Google Glass, before the introduction of the GDK.

Answer (score 0):

For the official SDK as per [this question on Android Wear Developers Google+ page](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+EliezerGraber/posts/CwEKvC5BjRm):

> You can use the same notification APIs on the wearable that you use on a phone by writing an android wear app. If you need to trigger that notification from the phone, you can use the Wearable apis in Google Play Services to send messages to trigger them.